# ng test --no-watch --watch=false never exiting in gitlab CI

Tags: node.js, jestjs, gitlab, angular-cli, angular-test

As the title says, I simply want to run `ng test` from within gitlabCI.. but all the flags I've seen mentioned don't affect anything.. the routine just sits and sits.  are these flags enough or do I need to setup `jest.config.js` ? I see mention of `karma.conf.d` in other tutorials but I do not have that file at all in the project

**package.json**

```
  "scripts": {
    "affected:apps": "nx affected:apps",
...
    "test:ci": "ng test --watch=false --no-watch",
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
run-ng-test-ci:
  tags:
  - juju
  stage: test
  image: registry.gitlab.com/jrgemcp-public/gitlab-cicd-docker/build-mahrio-docker:latest
  script:
  - node --version
  - npm --version
  - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline --ignore-scripts --quiet
  - npm run test:ci
```

```
$ node --version
v14.20.0
$ npm --version
6.14.17
```

EDIT: Seems it's perhaps a Jest issue

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/runner-hangs-sometimes-after-all-jest-tests-are-completed/38853